# C#: PictureBox on the Panel question

Tags: c#, panel, picturebox

How to get the seen (user) region of the PictureBox with autoSize mode in the scrollable panel?

Comment: Can you please post some code for what you have tried?  Also, can you give us some more explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BiggsTRC To invalidate the seen rectangle only. I have a scrollable panel and an AutoSized PictureBox, looks like this: http://clip2net.com/s/VzkW     I tried PictureBox.ClientRectangle, but this didn't work like i want - to get the only visible part of the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
                pictureBox.Invalidate(new Rectangle(
                    Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.X),
                    Math.Abs(panel.AutoScrollPosition.Y),
                    panel.Width, panel.Height));
```